# shared gradle files, need to exclude useJUnitPlatform for projects that do not use junit 5

Tags: gradle, configuration, dependencies

I use shared gradle files for code quality on multiple projects which use junit 4.  I am creating a new service in which I would like to take advantage of junit 5.   The problem I have is that I need a way to only include useJUnitPlatform when the project has the junit-jupiter-engine dependency.   I can get the dependencies with configurations.testCompile but I have been unable to find a good solution to add a conditional that will include useJUnitPlatform if and only if the junit-jupiter-engine exists.

I would like to stay with shared gradle files for the code quality and keep older projects that utilize junit4 to continue to use it until I decide to upgrade.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
test {
    configurations.testCompile.each { println it }

    if (???) {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an inefficient way:

```
 def junit5 = false
 configurations.testCompile.each { lib -> 
    if( lib.toString().contains("junit-jupiter-api") ) {
        junit5 = true;          
    }
 }

 if (junit5) {
 }
```

I was looking for a more direct or efficient way of doing this.